# Check MST validity given a graph with intervals as edges costs

Tags: algorithm, minimum-spanning-tree

I literally bashed my head trying to figure this question.
Given an undirected and connected graph G , all the edges in G have unknown costs but it is known the interval of each cost for each edge for example the cost of edge e is in the closed interval [i,j] where i and j are real numbers. I am also given a spanning tree of G named T. I need to create an algorithm to check if T can be a minimum spanning tree of G or not.
I tried connecting this problem to network flow but I could not reach a solution. Is there any a hint for finding a solution to a problem like this?

Comment: You must be skipping some details. Because the problem you mentioned is unsolvable. There are plenty of intervals for which a spanning tree can be both minimum or not depending on the actual values of the edges.

Comment: This is the question. There are no missing details

Comment: Then the problem is unsolvable. Consider nodes a, b & c all connected to one another with edges each in interval [1, 10]. If T contains a-b & b-c, is it MST? Answer: Depends on the actual values of the edges a-b, b-c & c-a.

Comment: @merlyn I think the question is if it's **possible** that (with the right assignments of edge costs) the given treen is a minimum spanning tree, not whether it **is**. In your example, if the intervals for all three edges were identical, then any tree of two edges **can** be an MST. At least that's the way I read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be solved using [linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming). Checking if T can be a minimum spanning tree amounts to checking the feasibility of a set of linear constraints on a set of |E| variables, one for each edge of the graph. The variable x(u,v) corresponds to the weight of the edge (u,v). That is, a feasible solution to the linear program is an assignment of weights to the graph edges such that T is a minimum spanning tree. So, for a start, each variable x(u,v) is constrained to be within the specified interval.

The other constraints, which I'll specify shortly, are designed to be satisfied if and only if T is a minimum spanning tree under the assignment that solves the program.

To understand why under every assignment that satisfies the following constraints T must be a minimum spanning tree, you have to convince yourself of the following property of minimum spanning trees:

A spanning tree T is a minimum spanning tree if and only if for every edge (u,v) not in T and every edge `e` in the path from u to v in T, `w(u,v)>=w(e)`. This property follows from [the cut property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree#Cut_property).

So, to check if T can be a minimum spanning tree, one should check the feasibility of the linear program defined by the following set of constraints.

- For each edge in the graph, `i(u,v)<=x(u,v)<=j(u,v)`.
- For each edge `(u,v)` not in T and each edge `e` in the path from `u` to `v` in T, `x(u,v)>=x(e)`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint I think I got the answer now